# Issues with KeyError: 0

Tags: python, keyerror

Im having issued where my code keeps saying `KeyError: 0`, I have searched all over and couldn't find a way to fix this

```
    student_scores = {'0':65.0, '1':54.7}
    average_score = 66.0
    i = 0
    for v in student_scores:
      if student_scores[i] >= average_score:
        above_avg_check = "{} {}".format(student_names[i], student_scores[i])
        above_avg.append(above_avg_check)
        print(above_avg_check)
      i += 1
```

I am not sure on what to do, `i` is both a counter and the key of `student_scores`, so I can use it in a while loop.

Comment: Your dict as `'0'` as a key, but your looking for `0`. `'0'` and `0` are not the same thing

Comment: 0 and '0' are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You're checking an integer index while your 0 index is actually a string.

This code compiles for me on repl, just convert your index values to strings before trying to find them

```
student_scores = {'0':65.0, '1':54.7}
average_score = 66.0
i = 0
for v in student_scores:
  if student_scores[str(i)] >= average_score:
    above_avg_check = "{} {}".format(student_names[str(i)], student_scores[str(i)])
    above_avg.append(above_avg_check)
    print(above_avg_check)
  i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .items() method and get the scores in a much more simple way. The you can format your string based on the student and their score within your for loop.

```
student_scores = {'0': 65.0, '1': 54.7}
average_score = 65.0
i = 0
above_avg = []

for student, score in student_scores.items():
    if score >= average_score:
       above_average_check = '{}:  {}'.format(student, score)
       above_avg.append(above_average_check)
       print(above_average_check)
    i += 1
```

And here is your output:

```
0: 65.0
```

This will get you the output that you are looking for as you iterate through each key and its corresponding value.